playwright Pagination navigation and selecting row based on text
I have a table with data that is paginated, the objective of the test is to find an element and click on it to verify some data, the constraint is that I would not know in which page this element is located, when adding/removing data the element changes places.
I had created the following code:
async searchOrgInOrgListTableNavigating(name: string) {
    //Setting up the locator.
    // let orgElement =  this.page.getByText(orgName,  { exact: true });
    // let orgElement =  this.page.locator(`//a[text()=" ${name} "]`);
   
    // Make sure that we are starting the process of selecting from page one
    await this.paginationElements.getByText("1").click();
    let found = false;
    // Obtain all pages to later click on each.
    for (const pElement of await this.paginationElements.all())
      // We'll work on each page element except on previous / next elements
      if (found == false){

        if(await pElement.textContent() != 'Previous' && await pElement.textContent() != 'Next'  ){
          // clicking on page.
          await this.checkIfOrgNameIsPresent(name)
          await pElement.click({force: true});
          await pElement.isEnabled();
          await sleep(1000);
          console.log('Page Number: ' + await pElement.innerText())

        }
      }
  }
  
async checkIfOrgNameIsPresent(name:string ){
 
    await sleep(1000)
    if(await this.page.locator(`//a[text()=" ${name} "]`).isVisible()){
      console.log(`Pase por aca 1`)
      await sleep(1000)
      await this.tableRowOrgList.filter({ hasText: org_name }).click()
    }
  }

I know the above code needs lots of improvements, I've trying to solve this and made some changes.
So, the result of executing those methods is that, it goes page by page, and when it reaches page 4 where the element is present, it does not click on it, it ignores it, and I have a hunch, and it's related to the table not refreshing quick enough.
Do you have any idea?


Try following code:
    async searchForOrganization(name: string) {
    await this.paginationElements.getByText('1').click();

    const matchingRow = this.tableRow.filter({hasText: name});
    while (await this.nextButton.isEnabled()) {
        if (await matchingRow.isVisible()) {
            await matchingRow.click();
        } else {
            await this.nextButton.click();
        }
    }
}

Make sure that matchingRow locator points to a clickable element, if the organization name is a link try clicking on the link instead.

I´ve had a similar problem like you.
Fetch data how many pages you have.
let data_found = false
const pagination = page.locator('<your_locator_of_pagination') //if you have always the same amount of page you don´t need to do a count 
expect(pagination).toBeVisible() //to ensure page is loaded because .count() can be flaky at this time

for (let i = 0; i < pagination.count(); i++) {  //.count() should provide you the last page
    await page.getByText('Next').click() //or getByRole('button', {name: 'Next', exact: true)
    //here you could add some verification the next page is properly loaded because in headless mode PW is very fast and probably table hasn´t loaded the data.
    try {
        await expect(page.getByText('<my_text_i_look_for>')).toBeVisible()
        data_found = true
        break
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(`not found on page ${i}`)
    }
}
expect(data_found).toBeTruthy()

